# Symfony2 - Query Builder multiple orderBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have the following code

```
public function queryAssociationsSorted($id){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->leftJoin('a.category', 'c')
            ->where('a.job = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            //->addOrderBy('c.rank', 'DESC')
            //->addOrderBy('a.updated', 'DESC')    
            ->add('orderBy','c.rank DESC THEN a.updated DESC')       
            ;

    return $query = $qb->getQuery();
}
```

and this or the commented out options both only sort by a.updated. I have looked at other posts on this subject and can't find a solution. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and this is the result yu want:

---

id - rank - updated

---

xx -  4  - 2014-01-01

xx -  3  - 2014-01-02

xx -  3  - 2014-01-01

---

This actually works:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->leftJoin('a.category', 'c')
            ->where('a.job = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->addOrderBy('c.rank', 'DESC')
            ->addOrderBy('a.updated', 'DESC')    
            ;

return $query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: I tried this at the time, and I don't know why it didn't work, maybe a bug in a particular version I was using. I now use this frequently and it works

Comment: See other answer for a reason why this didn't work in the original context. Hope this helps someone

Comment: Though an old topic, but in case someone is looking for a solution in Symfony 5, ->orderBy('c.rank', 'DESC')
 ->addOrderBy('a.updated', 'DESC')

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how doctrine works with multiple sort by..

why dont you try to use dql or even raw sql query?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Edit:

something like that will work I think:

```
->add('orderBy','c.rank DESC, a.updated DESC')
```

If you still have no success the raw sql query will save you ;)

Comment: I'm not sure too but, take a look, there's an "operator" called "addOrederBy" so I suppose that our "unsurness" isn't motivated :)

Answer (score 0):

Over a year later and I've stumbled across the correct answer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34296272/2414847) by @red777

This will help you:

> `$adapter = new DoctrineORMAdapter($queryBuilder, false);` 
>   Had the same problem this morning. By default Pagerfanta is treating your query as
>   one with joins. Setting second argument to false makes it use simple
>   query handling.
>
> In Kunstmaan Bundle, in AdminListConfiguration class, you have to
>   overide function that is creating Pagerfanta, if you want to sort
>   simple entity.

The syntax in the query had always been correct, but the error crept in in the DoctrineOrmAdapter. Adding false as the second parameter sorted the problem